# Browserify Page Specific Modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, browserify

I am new to Browserify but I think I am missing something. From what I can tell I have to load every single module for my app into bundle.js but I am totally lost as to how to call functions, objects etc for specific pages.

For instance, this is my main.js file:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var mainUI = require('./main-ui');
var foodGrid = require('./food-grid');
mainUI();
```

The `mainUI();` bit is fine, as I need that to execute on every page to make my sidebar to work.

However, foodGrid is something that I only want to load when I visit the food page. If I do:

```
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var mainUI = require('./main-ui');
var foodGrid = require('./food-grid');
mainUI();
foodGrid();
```

Then `foodGrid()` is called on every page, this is not correct.

foodGrid() is defined as:

```
module.exports = function () {
    console.log('Test');
})
```

I can not see a way of getting this to work since everything is bundled into bundle.js, without doing some logic around the functions to determine if the user is on a certain page, which seems ridiculous.

My food page is:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Enquiries
@stop

@section('body')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h3>Food</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="food_controls" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            Control
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><img width="20" src="{!!asset('images/loader.gif')!!}"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Start typing to search...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="foodGrid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop

@section('js')
    {!! HTML::script('js/libs/kendo.all.min.js') !!}
    <script>
        enquiriesGrid();
    </script>
@stop
```

The above gives me the error that foodGrid() is undefined.

Can someone tell me how to work with this? I must being missing something big.

(I am using Laravel 5, that is what all that blade syntax is)

---

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('main.js');
});
```

Comment: If you want different modules for different portions of your site that are truly separated (you're loading the app again on a different page) then you can create a different bundle file. Otherwise, what's the point of having page specific functions?

Comment: How else could I run functions that are specific to a certain page on that page? It was very easy in RequireJs. I am trying to move away from that as many places say Browserify is much better.

Comment: Well in "single page applications" you load one bundle file because pages are really just stateful illusions that provide history. If you truly have separate pages, meaning you're loading bundle files on page load, you have to have different bundle files (home_bundle.js, food_bundle.js), which is perfectly fine and completely typical approach.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. I'm not making a single page app. Won't this mean I will have a huge gulpfile for mixing all the various js files for each and every page?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could create an array of filenames that correspond to  your pages and run a task in a loop. Luckily a long unwieldy gulpfile is worth the tradeoff of module bundling.

Comment: @azium Please see my edit. How to specify which files to add to a bundle? E.g. ones for bundle.js (the main one) and food-bundle.js